# Multiple asynchronous URL requests in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I have almost Ten url which provide some data in json formate and XML formate from different site. Now i want call all url asynchronously to use multithreade and i want get one notification when finish all response.So how i can achieve this functionality in ios.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't ask others to do your work for you!  
Read about dispatch_async, NSURLConnection and NSNotificationCenter.  
Maybe static is also a good thing to read about for the counter...

Comment: use NSOperationQueue.i had question on this   http://stackoverflow.com/q/25503814/3282447 it may useful for you

Comment: You could also use [Bolts](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) to coordinate the requests.